# How to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath to navigate to a specific tableview controller? (Swift)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, didselectrowatindexpath

I know I need to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but despite searching I can't seem to find a simple explanation.

I wish to use a `TableView` as an **index** for 10 other `ViewControllers`, but am having problems finding a simple resource that explains how to link each cell to a subsequent `TableViewController`.

Comment: Exactly what you want? please clear explain in brief.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for responding - I have a tableview with multiple cells. When a user clicks on a cell, I would like to navigate to a specific tableviewcontroller.

Comment: instead of multiple tableViewController , you have to use only one! and pass the data to tableViewController which you want to show on click event of didselectrowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Sorry, I think there is a little confusion. I don't need to pass any data, I simply need to navigate

Comment: so what are you showing in tableviewController!

Comment: Do you really need 10 different table view controllers (i.e. different subclasses of UITableViewController)? Usually you define one or maybe a couple subclasses to navigate to, and you set properties based on the selection that was made, i.e. in prepareForSegue.

Comment: Hello @saurabh, thank you for your insights. 

I'm a noob, and as such it's a little hard to articulate using the correct vernacular. I really only need 1 subclass of UITableviewcontroller, but a searching for a way to display different data based on the initial user selection.

e.g

I have a database of exercises grouped by bodypart (category).

When a user selects "Arms" in the parent, the child UITableviewcontroller displays every exercise for arms.

Whereas if they select "legs", the child UITableviewcontroller displays every exercise for legs.

Comment: are you getting array For bodyParts??e.g. array for "Arms" etc??

Comment: THANK YOU! so much of my time has been spent trying to articulate the problem in a way to get help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are getting Dictionary for bodyParts then you should use like this:
e.g.

```
NSDictionary *bodyparts; //containg data from database
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let tblView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Identifier") as UITableViewController
    switch(indexPath.row)
    {
        //data is array of tableviewcontorller
    case 0:
        tblView.Data = [bodyparts objectForKey:@"Arms"];//if You are getting array for key "Arms"
        break;
    case 1:
        tblView.Data = [bodyparts objectForKey:@"Legs"];
        break;
    and so on....
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

you have to set storyboard identifier in storyboard

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    // Show your screen here 
}
```